# When pressing button, setState works only on second press

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pagination, state

I'm trying to increment page state on a button press. When I press the button, state is 1. It works only after next press.

```
  const { state, fetchMissions } = useContext(MissionContext);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const loadMoreData = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
    if (state.missions && page !== 1) {
      fetchMissions(page);
    }
  };

      <Button title="load more data" onPress={loadMoreData}></Button>
```

Also using navigationEvents

```
 <NavigationEvents onWillFocus={() => fetchMissions(page)} />
```

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous. The value does not have to be updated on the next line.

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState
>
> Source: [reactjs.org, Why is setState giving me the wrong value?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)

I would recommend to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

```
const { state, fetchMissions } = useContext(MissionContext);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const loadMoreData = () => {
  setPage(page + 1);
};

useEffect(()=>{
   // this is called only if the variable `page` changes
   (state.missions && page !== 1) && fetchMissions(page);
}, [page]);
```

> By default, effects run after every completed render, but you can choose to fire them only when certain values have changed.
>
> Source: [reactjs.org, useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

So I've put `[page]` as second argument to tell React when to call this part of code.